# Unable to fetch vimeo video frame using this code

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

```
function rm(a) {
var p = document.getElementById(a);
imgtag = "";
ifrtag = "";
ifrsrc = "";
ifrtb = -1;
img = p.getElementsByTagName("img");
ifr = p.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i < ifr.length; i++) {
    ifrsrc = ifr[i].src;
    if (ifrsrc.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/") != -1) {
        ifrtb = i;
        break
    }
  else (ifsrc.indexOf("//player.vimeo.com/video") != -1 {
    ifrtb = i
    break
           }
}
if (ifrtb != -1) ifrtag = '<div class="entry-video"><iframe width="840" height="472" src="' + ifrsrc + '?vq=medium&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
else if (img.length >= 1) imgtag = '<div class="entry-image"><a href="' + y + '"><img class="thumb" src="' + img[0].src + '" /></a></div>';
else imgtag = '<div class="entry-image no-image"><a href="' + y + '"><img class="thumb" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-G9M2DTCTUwM/Tlh-2pwtc5I/AAAAAAAABKM/kCJg-Kf3W2M/no_image_yet.jpg" /></a></div>';
p.innerHTML = ifrtag + imgtag + '<div class="entry-container"><div class="entry-content"><h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' + y + '">' + x + "</a></h1><div class='meta-info'><a class='post-img' href=" + w + "><img class='authorimg' src=" + z + " /> <abbr>" + v + "</abbr></a>  | <span style='margin:0 0 0 1%;'>" + t + "</span></div><div class='clr'></div><p style='padding-top:3%'>" + stripTags(p.innerHTML, 30) + "...</p></div></div>"
}
```

I am using this code to get video frames from the blog posts of my blogger site.

I guess I've not written correct " *if and else* " statement that's why code is not working.
Can anyone please correct my mistakes so that video from both you tube and vimeo can be fetched using correct *if and else* statement.

Comment: HOW is this not working? You get the wrong frame? No frame at all? Code crashes your server? Perhaps if you put in some time properly formatting all of that so your lines aren't 6 miles wide, it'd be easier to follow. Have you done ANY debugging yourself? e.g. looked at the generated html using a DOM inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note about your code, when defining variables you should either do this:

```
var firstVar = 'something';
var secondVar = 'something';
var thirdVar = 'something';
```

OR:

```
var firstVar = 'something',
    secondVar = 'something',
    thirdVar = 'something';
```

The difference is that if you want to omit the need for the `var` prefix, you need to end the first variable definition with a comma instead of a semicolon.

Comment: Yeah! Finally I succeded to fetch video frames...
Thanks :)